# Determine if Flash Player Debugger is connected from ActionScript

Tags: actionscript-3

I know that [`Capabilities.isDebugger`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Capabilities.html#isDebugger) will tell you if the current Flash Player is a debug player, but is there a way from AS3 to determine if it is connected to a debug session?

The reason I want to do this: I'm currently sending all log messages to the JS `console.log`, like this:

```
function log(msg:String){
    trace(msg);
    if(ExternalInterface.available)
        ExternalInterface.call("console.log", msg);
}
```

However, I would prefer to only do this when I'm not already seeing the trace statements in the debug output panel in my IDE (Flash Builder, IntelliJ IDEA, etc). Something like this:

```
function log(msg:String){
    trace(msg);
    if(ExternalInterface.available && !Capabilities.isDebuggerConnected)
        ExternalInterface.call("console.log", msg);
}
```

If I use `Capabilities.isDebugger` instead of the made-up `isDebuggerConnected`, then it will never show log messages in the JS console while I'm using a debug player, but I do want to see the log messages if I'm not connected to the debugger. I know I could still monitor flashlog.txt, but I'd prefer to see them in the JS console if I'm not actively seeing them in a connected debug session.

Yes, I admit, this is a rather unusual thing. :) If it was easy to do, it would be nice, though.

Comment: I don't know if this is an answer or a comment ;) I think that you can use `Capabilities.playerType` to know if the current Flash player is an `ActiveX` or a `PlugIn` and at the same time not a debug version, so you can use JS, otherwise disable it.

Comment: Well I want to use JS when `ExternalInterface.available` *unless* the debugger is connected (because in that case the logs are shown in the Flash debug console). The `playerType` doesn't really matter to me.

Comment: What I meant is, if the `playerType` is in [`ActiveX`, `PlugIn`] (browser) and the Flash player is not a debugger, so sure you need JS, otherwise, disable it because you aren't using a browser so you don't need it.

Comment: Hm, but my problem is not determining if JS is available, for that I can just use `ExternalInterface.available`, nor is my problem whether the current player is capable of debugging, but rather whether the player **is** connected to a debug session. I'm guessing this isn't possible.